# I have a piece of html/javascript that need to be opened in a new page, but I'm using Wix.com

Tags: javascript, html, velo

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function randomlinks() {
    var myrandom = Math.round(Math.random() * 5)
    var links = new Array()
    links[0] = "wix website here"
    links[1] = "wix website here"
    links[2] = "wix website here"
    links[3] = "wix website here"
    links[4] = "wix website here"
    links[5] = "wix website here"
    window.location = links[myrandom]
  }
</script>
<form>
  <input button type="button" value="Start Taking Notes!" onClick="randomlinks()">
</form>
```

This is the code that I have in wix right now. I have replaced the links to the website for obvious reasons and replaced it with "wix website here." I hope some one can help me figure out where to put a piece of code to open these links in a new tab.

Edit: I should also put that right now when I click the button to bring me to the links they are opening in wix's custom built iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `window.open()` method, and set the "target" to "_blank" - this is the equivalent of setting an `<a target="_blank">`, but through JS:

Replace your `window.location=links[myrandom]`, with:

```
window.open(links[myrandom], "_blank");
```

And this should work fine :)

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help. Don't forget to "tick" the answer, if this is what you used, and upvote if the answer is useful :)

Comment: @GeoffJames He cannot upvote your answer, he need at leas 15 reputations.

Comment: Thanks @SoftwareEngineer171! Good point. Can't edit - so I'll add: "When you can" :)

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer171 FYI: I think we might have confused the "upvote" and "accept" constraints - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235 - You need 15 reps to upvote; and can't accept an answer until 15 mins after it's posted :)